# TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument:

Tags: python, django, lambda, factory-boy

I'm trying to populate my Django project with some random data using factory_boy and faker. However, when I try to create an instance of my UserFactory object I'm getting the error TypeError: () missing 1 required positional argument: 'a'.

It seems to have something to do with the fake_date and date_joined attributes and their lambda functions. A couple of the tutorials I've found have laid out using lambda functions in this way for the Factory objects but it isn't working for me.

```
import datetime
import factory
import faker
from dataStoreApp.models import Category, Goal, Transaction
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

fake = faker.Faker()


class CategoryFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):

    class Meta:
        model = Category

    name = factory.Iterator(['Category1', 'Category2',
                             'Category3', 'Category4',
                             'Category5', ], cycle=False)


class UserFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    FACTORY_HIDDEN_ARGS = ('fake_date', )

    class Meta:
        model = User

    fake_date = factory.LazyAttribute(
    lambda a: datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))
    date_joined = factory.LazyFunction(lambda a: a.fake_date)
    first_name = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda b: fake.first_name())
    last_name = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda c: fake.last_name())
    email = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda e: 'test' + '@test_email.com')



class GoalFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Goal


class TransactionFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
```

When running in the python console I get the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\factory\base.py", line 568, in create
    return cls._generate(enums.CREATE_STRATEGY, kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\factory\base.py", line 505, in _generate
    return step.build()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\factory\builder.py", line 272, in build
    step.resolve(pre)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\factory\builder.py", line 221, in resolve
    self.attributes[field_name] = getattr(self.stub, field_name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\factory\builder.py", line 363, in __getattr__
    extra=declaration.context,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\factory\declarations.py", line 59, in evaluate
    return self.function()
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'a'
```

Comment: Note that `FACTORY_` methods [were removed in 2.5](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html#upgrading).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You create function with argument `a` in code

```
lambda a: ....
```

but it seems program expects function without arguments

```
lambda: ...
```

Comment: How is it any different from the code in this example tutorial? I'm still not sure where I'm going wrong. https://i.imgur.com/HDqwUKZ.png

Comment: SOLVED: LazyFunction should have been LazyAttribute in date_joined